# Como retornar datas com contagem zero

Tags: postgresql, funções

Estou tentando usar a função *coalesce* para retornar 0 quando minha consulta não tiver um valor de retorno, porém já tentei de mil e uma formas e não consigo retornar 0 de jeito nenhum. Quero saber onde estou errando:

```
select
    case 
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 1 then '01.Jan'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 2 then '02.Fev'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 3 then '03.Mar'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 4 then '04.Abr'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 5 then '05.Mai'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 6 then '06.Jun'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 7 then '07.Jul'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 8 then '08.Ago'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 9 then '09.Set'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 10 then '10.Out'
        when date_part('month', p.data_cadastro) = 11 then '11.Nov'
        else '12.Dez'
    end as mes,
    coalesce(count(*), '0'), 
    s.descricao as situacao
from
    tb_historico p
    inner join
    tb_situacao s on s.id_situacao = p.id_situacao
where
    date_part('year', p.data_cadastro) = 2015
    and s.descricao = 'APROVADO'
    and id_usuario = 10
    and id_tipo_projeto = 1
group by mes, s.descricao
order by mes
```

Comment: O **Coalesce** retorna **para o campo da projeção** o valor passado no segundo parâmetro se o primeiro for nulo, quando não tiver retorno, não existe o campo da projeção e por isso não vai retornar nada. Qual a necessidade de retornar o campo como zero?

Comment: Eu quero que apareça o seguinte... Caso na contagem das tuplas de zero para algum mês, atualmente ele não aparece aquela linha, porém eu quero que apareça. Digamos que no mês de janeiro não teve nenhuma linha, eu quero que apareça 01.Jan | 0

Comment: uma gambiarra simples seria vc criar uma tabela com os 12 meses e fazer um left join...

Comment: Sim @iuristona hehe eu já tinha pensado nisto, mas meu sistema e bancos já estão em produção. Queria fazer alguma coisa maneira sem as gambiarras.

Comment: Tentou mudar `inner join` por `left join`?

Answer (score 2):

No Postgresql é possível gerar series de datas com a função `generate_series`. Fazendo um `right join` desta com o `from` da sua query original todas as datas serão retornadas:

```
select
    to_char(d.d, 'MM.Mon') as mes,
    s.descricao as situacao,
    count(*) as total
from
    tb_historico p
    inner join
    tb_situacao s on
        s.id_situacao = p.id_situacao
        and date_part('year', p.data_cadastro) = 2015
        and s.descricao = 'APROVADO'
        and id_usuario = 10
        and id_tipo_projeto = 1
    right join
    generate_series (
        '2000-01-01'::date, '2000-12-01', '1 month'
    ) d(d) on date_part('month', d.d) = date_part('month', p.data_cadastro)
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
```

Note que as condições foram migradas da cláusula `where` para a cláusula `from` evitando que elas transformem o `outer join` em um `inner join`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
select p.AcctStartTime, m, substring(date_format(m, '%m.%M'), 1, 6) mes from (
    select m from (
         select 1 m union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 
         union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 
            union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 
            union all select 11 union all select 12) meses) mm 
    left join radacct p on mm.m = date_format(p.AcctStartTime, '%c')
```

Utilizei uma tabela que eu tenho em mysql e você vai precisar adaptar pra sua.